# How to double click a word in a web page by Javascript in browser's console

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom-events

**HTML**:

```
<iframe .....
<p class="textClass"> Some Text.............
<span id="unique-id"> Double-Click Me</span>
</p>
</iframe>
```

**Requirement:**

I need to trigger the double-click to happen programmatically by passing Javascript in browser's console to double-click the word **Double-Click Me**. Once, I double-click a pop-up window will be opened where I can add comments for the double-clicked word.

**Solutions tried:**

1. Using Selenium's Actions class double-click method works only with Chrome browser and not works in Firefox, IE, Edge, and Safari.
2. Tried many Javascript available to double-click an element- nothing works

```
var evObj = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, 
view: window});
evObj.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

We're going to add an onclick event, set a variable of 0 to count the number of clicks.

Then we'll check if the number of clicks is 2, and if so then we'll prompt the user for a new word, grab the value and place it in place of the old word.

Assuming you're looking to change this multiple times, we need to either reset the variable to 0, or in my example, modulo the number of clicks by 2 and check if the remainder is 0 (ultimately seeing if it's an even number!), then we can very easily log the total number of clicks if that is at all relevant to you.

```
<p class="textClass"> Some Text.............
<span id="unique-id" onclick="double()"> Double-Click Me</span>
</p>
<script>
var clickNum = 0;
function double(){
    clickNum += 1;
    if (clickNum % 2 == 0){
        var newWord = prompt("Enter word: ");
        document.getElementById("unique-id").innerHTML = newWord;
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**: Okay, so apparently you want to be able to double click a word on a page. What you're going to need is a userscript (Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey would work).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @match        * //Add your website here so it doesn't execute on every page you visit!
// @author       You
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    document.getElementById("unique-id").click;
    document.getElementById("unique-id").click";
})();
```

I really hope this is what you want. If you mean something else then please carefully clarify it.

Comment: Note that if someone clicks the word and then comes back a minute later and clicks it again, that it **WILL** prompt. You can add a timer function in and replace the module % method with a simple reset.

Comment: I need to trigger the double-click to happen programmatically by passing javascript's in browser's console

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. You're looking for a userscript/browser extension. I'll add the code to my post.

Comment: If that is what you want (it to double click a word automatically), then perfect. I'll add in the second part to change the contents of the word for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below code

```
var Clickevent = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {'view': window});
document.getElementById('unique-id').dispatchEvent(Clickevent);
```

Answer (score 0):

So for me the following works for double-clicking:

```
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {bubbles:true, isTrusted:true});
document.getElementById('unique-id').dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```